# CSS Transition won't work on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a transition onmouse hover an div. The effect should be a text merging from the top to the middle of the div while the div turns from square to circle. The problem is that if in FireFox the square to circle effect works but not the text droping down from top, this effect only works on Chrome and IE. Does anyone encounter this before and can someone tell me why this is happening?
The code of my buttons are below:

```
#navigation{
font-size:14px;
float:left;
left:0;
height:100%;
position:static;
width:65px;
margin-top:6.5%;
margin-left:10%;
}


#tab1{
float:left;
width:65px;
height:65px;
left:0;
transition:all 1s, all 1.1s;
-webkit-transition:all 1s, all 1.1s;
-moz-transition:all 1s, all 1.1s;
margin-top:40px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
}

.tab1h{
width:65px;
height:65px;
visibility:none;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
transition:all 1s, all 1.1s;
-webkit-transition:all 1s, all 1.1s;
-moz-transition:all 1s, all 1.1s;
}


#tab1:hover {
border-radius:50%;
overflow:hidden;
visibility:none;
}


#tab1:hover > .tab1h {
visibility:visible;
float:left;
opacity:1;
padding-top:20px;
}
    <div id="navigationi">
            <a href="index.html" >
                <div id="tab1" style="background-color:#f5f4f0; font-size:14px;">
                    <div class="tab1h">
                    Home
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
</div>
```

So here is my html and css also here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MFcS5/.

Thanks,Victor

Comment: The HTML you've given us isn't valid. Please create a JSFiddle that demonstrates your problem. -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry forgot to close a div,but here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MFcS5/ . Thanks

Comment: What is transition `all 1s, all 1.1s` supposed to do?

Comment: it suppose to get the height and width of the transition,it's not necessary but in some cases it can be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `overflow:hidden` from `#tab1:hover` solves the problem. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFcS5/11/) showing it working as intended in Firefox (as well as Chrome and IE).

It could be caused by [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289): "CSS transitions don't start due to frame reconstruction of ancestor or self..."; changing the `overflow` causes `#tab1` to be redrawn at the same time as the transition is supposed to start, so its child `.tab1h` doesn't get to transition.

Comment: Thanks dude,it seems to work,never thought of that as i never seen the reason why to do it,but indeed it works.